# L2S call is causing an exception about null assignment of an int when attempting to retrieve entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, exception

I have the following code

```
    public JsonResult GetRequestDetails(int id)
    {
        TestRequest req = _context.TestRequests.Where(x => x.id == id).Single();
```

There's more to the function but that first line is where I get the following exception:

```
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.
```

Now in the debugger I can see that `id` is a valid integer, it's equal to 5 atm for the call that I am making. I then went to SQL and verified that there is a record with an id value of 5.  I tried changing `Single()` to `First()` at the odd chance the exception message was just wrong and more than one record existed, but the same exception occurs.

I am completely baffled on why this linq-to-sql call is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem was "not getting a row" the error would be different.

The problem *here* is in the materialiser - i.e. turning a retrieved row of data from an `IDataReader` into an object. I strongly suspect that one of the int columns on the row is `null`, but in the DBML is is marked as non-nullable.

Find which column this is, and either make it nullable in the DBML or remove the null from the database.

Comment: yep that was it!  One of my int fields was marked "Nullable: false" when it shouldn't have been.